# Is it possible to pass a list of arguments to a method without declaring them beforehand?

Tags: java

Given a method such as:

```
public void blit(int[] pos) {
   do stuff..
}
```

Is there a way to pass in a list of arguments without first declaring them?

For instance, in Python, I could do something like:

```
def blit(pos):
   stuf...

blit([20,50])
```

I can simply pass in a list that created specifically in the argument list. To do the equivalent in Java, it seems I have to first declare the array, and only then can I pass it to the method.

```
int[] coordinates = {20,50};
blit(coordinates);
```

Which is not a huge deal, but it'd be handy if I could just do something like,

```
blit({20,50});
```

But that, of course, doesn't work. I've also tried creating the array inside of the call like,

```
blit(new int[] = {20,40});
```

But again, no luck. So, perhaps a terrible question, but is there a way to pass lists of arguments to a method that mimics in part the behavior of Python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it in two ways:

```
blit(new int[] {20,40});
```

Or declare your method with varargs:

```
public void blit(int... pos) {}
```

and call it like this:

```
blit(20, 40);
```

Answer (score 2):

You were close:

```
blit(new int[] {20,40});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean anonymous array creation:

```
blit(new int[] {20, 40});
```

am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the variable number of arguments syntax:

```
public void blit(Object ... args)
{
}

blit(10, 20, 30);
```

If you want to pass homogeneous arguments, then a `List<type>` should be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax:

```
blit(new int[]{20, 40});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
  blit(new int[]{5,10});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `List`..............

`blit(new List<Integer>());`

Answer (score 0):

You could put a **`java.util.Map<String,Object>`** as the only argument of your method. (With key=name of the argument)

```
java.util.Map<String,Object> arguments=new HashMap<String,Object>();
List<Integer> positions=new ArrayList<Integer>();
positions.add(1);
positions.add(2);
arguments.put("pos",positions);

myfunction_call(arguments);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call it as `blit(new int[]{20,40});`

For reference types, you can declare method whis varargs:

```
 public void blit(Integer... pos) {
    //do stuff..
 }
 // and the array creation code will be inserted by the compiler:
 blit(20,40);
```